# How to set custom attribute to the div element through JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div that needs to be added an attribute after button click, I have tried like,

```
 $('#item').prop('data-sck', "{rtl: true}");
```

I need the final output as

```
<div id="item" data-sck='{"rtl": true}'>

</div>
```

Comment: it saying undefined

Comment: Just try to change the .prop to .attr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `attr` function :

```js
$('#item').attr('data-sck', "{rtl: true}");

console.log($('#item').attr('data-sck'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div id="item">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
 var sck = {rtl: true}

 $('button').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   $('#item').attr('data-sck', JSON.stringify(sck));
});
```

Comment: Attribute values are strings. This would produce `data-sck="[Object object]"`

Comment: so it should be $('#item').attr('data-sck', JSON.stringify(sck));

Comment: Yes... or use `data()` to store as object